# Is there a safer way of moving a branch pointer than `git reset --hard`?

Tags: git

When working with git, I tend to use a lot of "advanced" features to rewrite and reorganize my local history before pushing to the remote. One command I frequently use to change the commit my current branch is pointing to is `git reset --hard <commit>`. Unfortunately, this command has some potentially undesirable effects when run with uncommitted changes in your local directory. I have lost work (though usually not much, I tend to commit often) in the past due to this feature.

Is there an alternative to `git reset --hard` for changing the commit my *current branch* is pointing to, which doesn't cause a loss of data when I have uncommitted changes in my working directory? (Ideally, I would want something like `git checkout` which changes my current branch pointer instead of changing HEAD.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you look for something *like* `git checkout`, when you can just use `git checkout`?

The option you're looking for is `-B`, which checks out the specified ref and either creates a new branch from it, or updates an existing branch. It works even if you specify the branch you're already on.

Comment: Git v1.7.3 Release Notes
...
  "git checkout -B <it>" is a shorter way to say "git branch -f <it>"
   followed by "git checkout <it>"

Comment: @UweGeuder Either the release notes are incomplete, then, or this was relaxed in a later version. If you're on branch `master`, `git branch -f master` is an error ("fatal: Cannot force update the current branch"), but `git checkout -B master <ref>` does work. I've tested this with Git 1.9.4.

Comment: That's almost perfect. I wasn't aware of that option for `git checkout`. Now I just have to write an alias which handles filling in the "current branch" so I don't have to type it every time. Thanks for your help. ;-)

Comment: @hvd I guess the explanation in the release notes was an attempt to be very concise, which ended up to be incorrect not taking this special case into account that the branch is not switched. And my thinking was equally sloppy, not recognizing that your question is this special case and testing it before commenting. Anyway, my main point was that -B was added in 1.7.3. So for example not available yet in Ubuntu Lucid or CentOS/RHEL 6.

Comment: For anyone who's interested, I'm now using the following alias:

    move-branch = !git checkout -B `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`

Answer (score 1):

These will preserve your changes

```
git reset --soft
```

or

```
git reset --mixed
```

After doing one of them, you could use `git diff` to evaluate if you want to throw the changes away.

Comment: The problem with this is that it preserves not just changes in my working directory, but also changes on the branch itself. I definitely want the changes on the branch reset, that's why I'm moving the branch pointer in the first place.